# security - folder 775 on a web server

Tags: web-services, apache, security

I have a general security question. How bad is it to have a folder with 755 rights on a web server? This is ls -l of the folder:

```
    drwxrwxr-x 11 apache apache
```

Comment: Why does world have read permissions? `700` sounds more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it means that the `apache` user and anyone in the `apache` group can write to that directory. Anyone else can read entries in there and enumerate them.

How *serious* that is depends entirely on what processes can be run under that user and/or group by untrusted users.

Comment: ok so no that serious..(well at least to what I know). I thought that when I had such a folder an easy hack could go like this: 1. use POST to post some file to that folder (from a script run remotely), 2. run that code and 3. gain control

Comment: @user965847, you should, at a bare minimum, run CGI or any external (untrusted by Appache) code as a different user. Additionally, the potential impact may depend exactly on _which_ directory that is.